# Google REST API to retrieve images in gcr.io

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-registry

I am looking to fetch images that are available gcr using a gcloud API.

I have tried `GET https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/images/myimage` but I wont get anything back.

If I remove remove `/myimage` from the call above, I get some images back but not the images on the GCR as compute returns GCE images.

I found `https://gcr.io/v2/myproject/myimage/tags/list` which does return the data I expect. But using this is not an option for me.

Is there an actual google API that returns something similar as the SDK `gcloud container images describe gcr.io/myproject/myimage` or as `https://gcr.io/v2/myproject/myimage/tags/list` ?

Comment: `https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/images` is for GCE images https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images, NOT for container images

Answer (score 4):

Google Container Registry (GCR) implements the [Docker Registry HTTP API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) for image management.

See Google's docs for Container Registry: [Docker Registry API](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/reference/docker-api).

You can confirm this to yourself by running any of the `gcloud container images` sub-commands with the `--log-http` flag to show the underlying REST API calls e.g.

```bash
gcloud container images list --log-http
```

You may find it useful to use commands like the above as an exemplar for using the API w/ GCR

It is useful that Google chose to implement Docker's API because it means that you can use e.g. `docker`, `podman` and any other existing tools that talk to the Docker API to interact with GCR.

The downside is that the API is not a Google API and so requires understanding Docker's methodology. In my experience, the APIs' a little gnarly.

Comment: A long time ago (!) I wrote [Adventures w/ Container manifests](https://medium.com/google-cloud/adventures-w-docker-manifests-78f255d662ff) which documents some of these methods with GCR. It's old but it may provide some help.