# How do I get the digest of an image on GCR or artifact registry with PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I would like to get the digest of an image with code.
At the moment I do it like this:

```
function findDigestForImage($imageNoDigest)
{
    $cmd = sprintf("gcloud container images describe %s --format 'value(image_summary.digest)'", $imageNoDigest);
    return rtrim(shell_exec($cmd));
}
```

Using shellexec to do:

```
gcloud container images describe eu.gcr.io/test/some-project:tag --format 'value(image_summary.digest)'
```

Using shellexec is not ideal.

---

I've read over almost all the code for https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-container-analysis/ but the documentation is kinda non existant and my PHP skills aint great.

Clarification: I'd prefer to use the library and do everything purely in code without invoking the shell. I also feel using any kind of shellexec or exec type of thing in your code is super poor security practice.

Comment: What is not ideal with using shellexec (for you)? You may perhaps want to share, so that it becomes more clear what _you're_ looking for.

Comment: Contact Google support for your issue that you have problems to locate the appropriate (PHP) API for `glcoud container images describe` (I don't know it). Container Analysis is perhaps not the right API, however the documentation of it exists here: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-analysis/docs and it is linked with the package documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-container-analysis/latest - perhaps you're looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I'd prefer to use the library and do everything purely in code without invoking the shell.

Comment: Yes, that clarifies a lot ([edit] that clarification into your question). For that, you need to find the API binding for `gcloud container images describe` first. From what I could see it is not _"Google Cloud Container Analysis"_ you currently have in use. This could also explain why didn't find anything in the repository. Additionally those are only PHP language bindings, better locate the right API first, then choose the appropriate PHP package.

Comment: Please also see this insightful Q&A answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73668240/367456

Comment: Use the command `glcoud container images describe IMAGE_NAME --log-http` to see the REST APIs used. Then you can look up the APIs and create your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and all the time spent answering my question! Really useful answers!